# Excel - deleting duplicate rows when col3 = col4

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Macros. I need excel macro code for the below logic:
col1 means column1,
col2 means column2

```
Sub TestDuplicates()
    in worksheet,
    for(each x = row) {
        for(each y = row+1) {
          if(x.col1 == y.col1 && x.col3 == y.col4 && x.col4 == y.col3) {
            Delete y
          }
        }
    }
End Sub
```

Comment: your code does not even compile, you should put some effort on it before posting.

Comment: that does not compile.. but i wrote algorithm so that any1 can understand

Comment: If it's just pseudocode that you offer, it helps to let us know in your OP.

Comment: He said he needed code for the below logic. "Below Logic" implies that it is pseudo code. It could have been more clear but I understood it. Plus if you really know vba then you can tell at the blink of an eye it won't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub deleteDuplicateRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, curRow As Long, checkRow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row - 1

For curRow = 2 To lastRow

    For checkRow = curRow + 1 To lastRow
        If ws.Range("A" & curRow).Value = ws.Range("A" & checkRow).Value And ws.Range("B" & curRow).Value = ws.Range("B" & checkRow).Value And ws.Range("C" & curRow).Value = ws.Range("C" & checkRow).Value Then
           ws.Rows(checkRow).Delete
        End If
    Next checkRow
Next curRow

End Sub
```

Checks the current row against all remaining rows starting at row 2.

Comment: Ooh, I seem to have misunderstood exactly what OP was asking to do.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: just a small modification to this solved my requirement.  And ws.Range("C" & curRow).Value = ws.Range("D" & checkRow).Value And ws.Range("D" & curRow).Value = ws.Range("C" & checkRow).Value

Comment: Yeah I wasn't exactly sure what you were comparing. Glad I could help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub TestDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = 1
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value = ws.Range("A" & lRow + 1).Value And ws.Range("C" & lRow).Value = ws.Range("D" & lRow + 1).Value And ws.Range("D" & lRow).Value = ws.Range("C" & lRow + 1).Value then
             ws.Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete
        End If

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I seem to have misunderstood your pseudocode somewhat, so this doesn't do quite what you asked.  Instead, it compares each row to the row directly after it, not to all remaining rows.  Since bbishopca already contributed an excellent solution to what you actually asked for, I'll just leave this here unedited in case someone finds it useful.

```
Sub AlmostTestDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each rw In ws.Rows
        If ws.Cells(rw.Row, 1).Value = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Cells(rw.Row, 1) = Cells(rw.Row + 1, 1) _
          And Cells(rw.Row, 3) = Cells(rw.Row + 1, 4) _
          And Cells(rw.Row, 4) = Cells(rw.Row + 1, 3) Then
            ws.Rows(rw.Row + 1).Delete
        End If
    Next rw
End Sub
```